# How can I determine the direction of a packet in a BPF_PROG_TYPE_SK_SKB verdict program?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

I am writing a [BPF_PROG_TYPE_SK_SKB](https://lwn.net/Articles/731133/) verdict program to make redirection decisions. How can I work out the direction of the packet (ingress/egress)?

I have access to the [local and remote port](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L2646-L2647) of each packet, but I am unable to determine which one is the source or destination port and so cannot determine the direction. Should this be possible? And if not then why not?

`uname -a`: Linux ubuntu-bionic 4.18.0-16-generic #17~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 12 13:35:51 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there are some very elegant solution. I solved this by using sockmap with only 2 elements: in that way, you dont have to deal with directions, because its trivial. Sadly, with this method, you have to make a sockmap for every socket pair.